# How to read previous line by using bufferedReader

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader

I am making a some large project. In that I am stuck at one place. I am using the following code to read from the file:

```
String str = null;
FileReader fr = new FileReader("H:\\Eclipse\\Emulator\\progin8085.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
str = br.readLine(); //using it in a loop from 0 to total_no_of_lines
```

Now I when I reached suppose at line 8(counting lines numbers while entering data to the file), I want to go back to line 3 or 4 or any and again want to read and execute each statement. How to read previous statements using BufferedReader only? If it is not possible, any other solution?

Comment: It is possible, but undesirable, via the mark() and reset() methods.  Why do you think you need to re-read data? It isn't usual.

Comment: I need to Read data back...like we use goto statements in c

Comment: Don't just repeat yourself. Answer the question.

Comment: well you can save lines in string array and go back and forth depending upon your requirement

Comment: @HarisMehmood: what if the data is too large??

Comment: @ADi so what ? Let it be

Comment: @HarisMehmood:  Let the JVM crash, right?

Comment: @HarisMehmood that's a strange thing to say.

Comment: Isn't it possible with buffered reader?

Comment: GOD, its in case the file fits the memory, obviously no one wants OutOfMemory exception to come.

Comment: You can either use `mark` and `reset` as @EJP suggests. Although if you need to go back to different lines depending on some logic you could always use a `FileChannel` and scan you file for the location of the lines - then use that information to essentially random access the file.

Comment: Oh I am sorry EJP, I actually forgot to see your comment... Thanks everyone...

Comment: @HarisMehmood I'm confused now. You said read it into memory. Someone else said what if it's too large?  You said that's fine. Now you're saying _obviously_ not if it's too large. So which is it?

Comment: Boris, its not possible with large files...that method of copying ibto string..

Comment: @Noname what method of copying into a `String`. I suggested no such thing.

Comment: I an talking of Haris...

Comment: @Noname I see. I'm aware that copying a large file into memory is not possible. I was just trying to encourage Haris to read answers to him comments properly and think before answering.

Comment: @Noname It's hard to see why you're addressing Boris when you're refers to a statement by Haris. You need to read what's posted here a lot more carefully in general.

Answer (score 2):

Some `Reader`s support marks.  You can use those to rewind the file.  A particularly useful `Reader` (imo) is the `LineNumberReader` and it supports marks.  This sort of code might suit your needs.

```
public static int final READ_AHEAD_LIMIT = 100000;

LineNumberReader lnReader = new LineNumberReader(reader);

while (youWantToRead) {
  ...
  if (mightBeInterestingLater) {
    lnReader.mark(READ_AHEAD_LIMIT);
  }
  ...
  if (nowWantToRewind) {
    lnReader.reset();
    // We're now at whatever place mark() was last called at.
  }
```

Comment: BufferedReader supports mark(). He doesn't have to change the reader. See the Javadoc.

Comment: Didn't mean to suggest it doesn't.  I just pointed out that LineNumberReader is useful, and it does support marks.

Answer (score -4):

Save all the lines of text file in **String[] StrArray** and do whatever you want.

Comment: Assuming the file fits into memory.

Comment: Ok...but any other way by which bUfferedReader can only does the required task?

Comment: @Noname EJP just said that you can do it through mark() and reset() method.

Comment: @Noname I answered that in my comment. The one containing the question that you're ignoring.

Comment: A bit of a violation of best coding practice here.